# Is it correct to say "a weapon with 1 meter of length"?

Tags: grammaticality

Is it correct to say "a weapon with 1 meter of length"?

I know there's an alternative way that I believe should be more common to say the same: "a 1 meter long weapon".

Are those sentences correct?

Comment: Saying "a weapon" and then specifying that it's a meter in length seems unusual. If you can see it well enough to know that's it's one meter in length, why don't you call it "a rifle" or "a sword" or "a halberd" or "a bladed weapon of a kind he hadn't seen before"?

Answer (score 0):

It is not correct to say that something has so much of any dimension. We can say that *something's* length, height or depth *is* so many units but a dimension is not is not treated as something which is in any sense *allocated* to the object because to do would mean that the amount of that dimension allocated could be changed.

We could change a dimension of something but only by fundamentally changing the object. For instance we could take a pike with a one and a half metre shaft (a weapon two metres *in* length if the head is half a metre long) and cut off one metre of the shaft to make it "a weapon one metre in length" but we can't then re-allocate more length to it, we can only change the object again by either replacing the shaft with, say, a one and a quarter metre shaft or by splicing a quarter-metre piece onto the shaft.

This is in contrast to, say, a building ten metres *in* height which could have eight metres *of* bunting attached to it because the bunting can be removed, replaced or augmented without changing the building.

There are several ways we can refer to a dimension of an object, geological feature or living entity but none of them treats the dimension as something which is allocated. Examples of most of these ways are:

> A weapon of one metre *in* length (The closest to your original)

> A weapon one metre *in* length (Similar to the above but wthout the "of". This is much more common)

> A weapon one metre long

> A weapon having a length of one metre (length is treated as a possessed attribute but not something which is allocated)

> A weapon having a length of one metre

Both the other dimensions are referred to in the same way and the same forms are used for everything, for example:

> A man two metres tall

> A road having a length of three hundred kilometres

> A mountain one thousand metres in height

> A building twenty metres deep

The same forms apply to age and weight

Comment: Normally these are used as prefix units without specifying which dimension is involved because it's so obvious: *a two-inch wasp, 
a three-foot weapon, a fifteen-gallon tank, a six-foot man, a two-mile well, a twenty-ounce mug, a thousand-mile highway, a ten-yard penalty, a thirty-knot headwind, a five-acre farm, a forty-fathom dive, a two-ton trailer.*

Comment: @tchrist I agree that your form is more common but I was trying to show that the OP's construction "one metre _of_ length" is never used. We do, as I said, use "a building with eight metres of bunting on it" but we don't say "a piece of bunting _with eight metres of length_" which was the form the OP was asking about.

Answer (score -2):

No, this is not idiomatic; you have at least three possibilities.

- It's a weapon *of length  one meter*. ([ref.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22of%20length%20one%20meter%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en))
- It' a *one meter long weapon*. ([ref.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a%20one%20meter%20long%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en))
- It's a weapon *one meter in length*. ([ref.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22of%20length%20one%20meter%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en))
- It's *a meter long weapon*. (*This fourth way of specifying the length seems to be used less often.* [ref.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Deformation_of_Glacial_Materials/tyQfYpt_SrcC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22a+meter+long%22&pg=PA119&printsec=frontcover): The view is due south towards the Southern Masson Range ( visible on the horizon ) with a meter long ice axe in the foreground.)

Here is an additional possibility pointed out by **user WS2**.

- It's a weapon *of one metre in length*. ([ref.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22of%20one%20meter%20in%20length%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en))

Comment: I would combine the first and the third into *It's a weapon of one metre in length*. I am not sure if the first is grammatical.  With the second sentence I would just add some hyphens *It's a one-metre-long weapon*. I'm only saying what I, a British person, would write. Others may disagree.

Comment: @WS2 How can you say that the grammaticality of the first is doubtful when you find numbers of examples in the reference?

Comment: @WS2 'It's a weapon of one metre in length' - leave out 'of' or 'in'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey For all practical purposes, yes. But in a formal expression I would use both - though perhaps leave out 'of', replacing it with a comma.

Comment: @LPH Well, I would definitely introduce a comma or, better still, an em dash.  *It's a weapon - of length one metre* or *It's a weapon, of length one metre*. Either of those would probably work.

Comment: @WS2 There is not a single case of a comma or dash in perhaps 50 cases that can be found in the reference. Is that a recent punctuation rule?

Comment: @LPH Probably more that a lot of people do not have much of a sense of what constitutes good English. As mentioned, I was only saying what I would do. Writing is an art - not a science.

Comment: @WS2 Your last remark amounts to a rather grim comment on the ability of an important part of your learned contemporaries to  appreciate the language…

Comment: @LPH Well - to be honest, I don't believe these Google Ngrams. They most probably work on a "garbage in, garbage out" principle. Who audits them?

Comment: @WS2 As often enough the publications are scientific ones it is most likely that auditing is carried out by scientific experts in the various fields, those having often a special duty as such examiners, either in universities or publishing firms.

Comment: Scientific publications describe lengths in terms different than ordinary language does. "A sword of length one meter" would be absolutely fine in an archaeological article, but it sounds much too stilted for the man in the street to use it.

Comment: @PeterShor You are selecting for your argument the term least likely to appear in those publications; the term we were talking about was "_of length one meter_", and that term is consistently found in scientific publications; you would have convinced yourself of that fact if you had  read as well as only perfunctorily the page in reference _for that expression_.